# Teleporting player to a given location in Minecraft SMP Vanilla

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can a player be teleported to given location in Vanilla SMP?

*Yes, I know `/tp` can teleport a player to another one, that's not what I'm after.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes

As of Minecraft [1.3.1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history) exact coordinates can be given as arguments to `/tp`, for example:

```
/tp @p 35 64 128
```

Comment: Plus Command Blocks.

Comment: Relative coordinates can be given by prefixing a number with `~`.

Comment: While I can't test it now, I'll just believe it and accept :)

Answer (score 5):

To add on to what fredley said in [his answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/102052/4775), you can specify a yaw and pitch (in degrees) as fourth and fifth arguments to the tp command. Further, you can prepend the tilde character (~) to any of the parameters to use positions or rotations relative to their current values.

See the [wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/SMP_Server_commands#Operator-only_commands) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that with just a vanilla server. See [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/SMP_Server_commands) for the list of all commands.

Comment: accepted the other answer because it was posted a little before, sorry :O